# Incomplete Recordset from ADODB Connection

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, excel-2013, recordset

I am trying to retrieve data from a worksheet that contains 80,000+ rows and print those values to a worksheet, but when I create a recordset and view its recordcount it only contains 16,492 records.

I am new to ADODB connections, so I am stumped as to what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
Sub testing()
    On Error Resume Next

    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Dim objCon As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recSet As ADODB.Recordset

    Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set recSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\nschneider\Desktop\Data Pulls_FY08 to Present_Companies 10, 20, 30, 40.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    recSet.Open "Select * FROM [Data$]", _
        objCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    If Not recSet.EOF Then
        Sheets(2).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset recSet
    End If

    '    Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    '        Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Name"), _
    '            objRecordset.Fields.Item("Number")
    '        objRecordset.MoveNext
    '
    '    Loop
End Sub
```

I've commented out the Loop as that was something I saw from a previous forum. Not sure if that is what I need.

Comment: In the worksheet that you are querying with that connection/sql statement, is there a blank record around row 16492? I'm wondering if Jet is stopping because of something like that.

Comment: @JNevill No, there are no blanks in the data. And there aren't any odd characters on that row that aren't already in the preceding rows.

Comment: Before you output your recordset, try putting there this code:

    IF recSet.RecordCount > 0 THEN
     recSet.MoveLast
     recSet.MoveFirst 
    END IF

Comment: @MarekStejskal thanks for the suggestion, but still getting the same result. I added this block right before the "If Not recSet.EOF" block.

Comment: I may be firing in the dark here, but have you tried getting the data into Excel by "normal" means first? Data->Connections->From Other Sources->From SQL server etc... I'm curious what the result would be then.

Comment: @MarekStejskal I tried using MS Query to access the Excel workbook containing he data, but I was getting errors upon refreshing - something about "expected 35 columns" or something like that. I'd like to keep the data in Excel since we're always refreshing the file. I don't want to get started on our IT bottleneck here preventing us from keeping this info in an easily accessible SQL table!

Comment: Try to get the data through purely Excel UI, no Access and no VBA, it's a matter of a few clicks. Then we'll see

Comment: This happens to me as well in the past. Try closing Excel and other Apps that might be eating memory (pc) and re-run your code. Also, try running it while your source file is open. One more thing, remove *On Error Resume Next* at the very top of the code. We might be overlooking some error somewhere which halts the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the connection string for Excel 97-2003 .xls file (specifically the part which says "Excel 8.0"). Excel sheets were limited to 65K rows back then. The connection string is then being applied to an Excel 2007-onwards .xlsx file where the maximum number of rows per sheet is over 1 million.

The older connection string works with newer .xlsx files but I've had issues when the row count on a sheet exceeds the old 65K maximum. Update the connection string to the correct one for a .xlsx file and see if that helps:

```
objCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\nschneider\Desktop\Data Pulls_FY08 to Present_Companies 10, 20, 30, 40.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
```

(I also removed an unnecessary ; after "HDR=Yes")

Comment: Where do I send the case of craft beer? This worked perfectly! Thank you. I thought about that old version for a moment, but I would have expected 65k rows instead of the 16k I was getting. But maybe there are other elements that play a role there. Anyway, thank you!